# Symfony2 Capifony app_dev.php not found

Tags: symfony, http-status-code-404, capistrano, capifony

I've deployed my Symfony2 website to an external development server, however it hasn't pulled the app_dev.php file from my github repository. app.php has been pulled and I can access the site from there but if I go to /app_dev.php I get a 404 not found because the file does not exist on the server. The file is definitely in my github repository though and is not within my .gitignore file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Capifony removes `app_*.php` files for security reasons. You shouldn't use them in production.

If you really need them, you can set the `clear_controllers` option to `false`:

```
set :clear_controllers, false
```

Comment: This isn't for production. I have development, staging and production servers and this is for my development server which is password protected.

Comment: Well, as they say, better safe than sorry. ;)

Comment: Not putting app_dev on production makes sense, but you can use different environments to load different configs, ex: app_mobile

Comment: @targnation, you *can* hit a nail with your head, but that doesn't mean you *should*. ;)

Comment: if people ever get to access app_dev.php on your servers, you have a SEVERE security flaw. safe defaults and the option to configure when you know what you do are security best practice.